# Regular expression for finding non-breaking string names in code and then breaking them up for SQL query

Tags: sql, regex

I am trying to devlop a regex for finding camel case strings in several code files I am working with so I can break them up into separate words for use in a SQL query.  I have strings of the form...

```
EmailAddress
FirstName
MyNameIs
```

And I want them like this...

```
Email Address
First Name
My Name Is
```

An example SQL query which I currently have is...

```
select FirstName, MyNameIs from MyTables
```

I need the queries in the form...

```
select FirstName as 'First Name', MyNameIs as 'My Name Is' from MyTables
```

Any time a new capital letter appears that should be a new grouping which I can pick out of the matched string.  I currently have the following regex...

```
([A-Z][a-z]+)+
```

Which does match the cases I have shown above but when I want to perform a replace I need to define groups.  Currently I have tried...

```
(([A-Z])([a-z]+))+
```

Which sort of works.  It will pick out "Address" as the first grouping from "EmailAddress" as opposed to "Email" which is what I was expecting.  No doubt there is something I'm misunderstanding here so any help is  greatly appreciated.

Comment: From what I gather, you want spaces in your column aliases.  I don't recommend the practice as a habit because it complicates referencing those columns within other SQL.  Use underscores instead of spaces, so you get `First_Name`, etc

Comment: Yes I do want spaces I would prefer not to use underscores to do that.  The column names from the SQL query are being using for display in an html table so using the space would make things show nicer to users.  I see your point and it is a good one although I think I am safe in this regard looking through the code base.  Will investigate further.

Comment: You could always Replace the underscores with spaces in your web page if need be.

Comment: True.  It's something to consider.

Comment: @Shawn Steward: +1, that's what I was going to suggest

Answer (score 1):

You can find words that use PascalCase or camelCase using the regex

```
\w+(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])\w+
```

You can then search the found words for

```
(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])
```

replacing all these occurences with a space.

In Python (just to show what I mean):

```
import re

def prettify(string):
    find_re = "\w+(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])\w+"
    split_re = "(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])"
    words = re.findall(find_re, string)
    for word in words:
        split_word = re.sub(split_re, " ", word)  
        # or use an underscore instead of a space
        string = string.replace(word, word + " as '" + split_word + "'")
    return string

print prettify('select FirstName, MyNameIs from MyTables')
```

Output:

```
select FirstName as 'First Name', MyNameIs as 'My Name Is' from MyTables as 'My Tables'
```